# 2006 Mac Pro - vmware fusion - snow leopard / VM's with Mavericks

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, vmware, mac-pro

Can a 2006 Mac Pro that can't go above Snow Leopard physically on the host run Mavericks with vmware Fusion virtually?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you can, and here's why ([from VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#intro-64bitguests)):

> VirtualBox supports 64-bit guest operating systems, even on 32-bit host operating systems provided that the following conditions are met:
>
> 1. **You need a 64-bit processor with hardware virtualization support (see Section 10.3, “Hardware vs. software virtualization”).**
> 2. You must enable hardware virtualization for the particular VM for which you want 64-bit support; software virtualization is not supported for 64-bit VMs.
> 3. If you want to use 64-bit guest support on a 32-bit host operating system, you must also select a 64-bit operating system for the particular VM. Since supporting 64 bits on 32-bit hosts incurs additional overhead, VirtualBox only enables this support upon explicit request.

VMWare Fusion [says something similar](https://www.vmware.com/support/fusion/faq/prod_info) (search the FAQ for "64-bit").

Assuming your Mac Pro is the 2.66 Quad Core, EveryMac [confirms](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_pro/specs/mac-pro-quad-2.66-specs.html) that your processor is 64-bit.  Give it a try, hit the forums, and good luck!